# XML To PSV - Specific Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

Im looking to transform a piece of XML into a Pipe|Seperated|Value format using XSLT.

However I only wish to select certain nodes to transform into this format.

How would I go about this?

The XML resides within a namespace which can be declared as "x"

Sample XML structure:

```
<Message>
    <Top>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
    </Top>
    <Middle>
         <c></c>
    </Middle>
    <Bottom>
         <d></d>
         <e></e>
         <f></f>
         <g></g>
    </Bottom>
</Message>
```

I wish to select the **values** of nodes: c, e and f.

Comment: `c`, `e`, and `f` go in one line, pipe separated then?

Comment: yes sorry to not confirm that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works perfectly thankyou, do you also happen to know how I could drop some of the entries onto a new line within a certain node.

Comment: well it's all about matches, if you can form an xpath that matches this certain node you can treat it specially, earlier template matches override later ones.

Comment: I understand that much, but would you use an ASCII code or is there a built in way to do this with xslt?

Comment: so for instance, if the e node should go onto a newline when its value is `foobar` you'd go: `<xsl:template match="e[text() = 'foobar']"> ...` and put a `<xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>` in there

Comment: oooh, i see, sorry didn't update.  Yes, `&#10;` is newline, you can also put a literal new line in the file, but I don't like that because it interferes with the automatic indentation features of my editor

Comment: Encountered one unforseen issue with this, I have two nodes of the same name but under different parent nodes, and for some reason "ParentNode/Node" isnt working on the match, do you know why?

Comment: what xslt processor are you using, also, xslt 1.0 or 2.0?  the match `parent/child` is perfectly legal in xslt 1.0 and should work.

Comment: 1.0, running it in VS2010. Using the XSLT debugger. Must be something to do with my namespace then though I cant see why as im doing "x:Parent/Child" where is the the declared namespace

Comment: ah, it's `x:Parent/x:Child` then probably?